# Powershell Move-Item logging

Tags: powershell

I would like some assistance getting a powershell script to work correctly. A piece of it is pasted below. Basically what I'm trying to do is to move all files in various subdirectories to another location. I can get the files to move and the folders to create fine, I'm just having a problem with getting the results to a text file. I've tried using out-file, but the txt file is empty. I've also tried start-transcript, but notepad doesn't seem to see line breaks and all the text bleeds together. Is there a better way to go about this? I'm using this basic command for testing.

```
Start-Transcript c:\log.txt
Move-Item c:\temp\*.* C:\Temp\2014 -Verbose -Force
Stop-Transcript
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just need to collapse the output file descriptors. According to the [about_Redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) page, it should work if you do the following:

```
Move-Item c:\temp\*.* C:\Temp\2014 -Verbose -Force *>&1 | 
    Out-File -FilePath $MyLogPath
```

Or if you want to see the output at the same time

```
Move-Item c:\temp\*.* C:\Temp\2014 -Verbose -Force *>&1 |
    Tee-File -FilePath $MyLogPath
```